# Can't get extra values from Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I am aware that to put values I can `intent.putExtra(key, value)` and to retrieve values we can `intent.getStringExtra(key)` but in following code its not behaving as expected. When retrieving values, I am getting `NUllPointer, printLn needs a message`.

Code where I am setting values:

```
public void SetAlarm(Context context, int seconds, String type) {
    CustomLog.logBlue(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(), "set alarm");

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE); //ONE_TIME = "oneTime"
    intent.putExtra("c", "ayush");

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), seconds * 1000, pi);

    CustomNotification.generateNotification(1, context, "Tracking enabled");
}
```

And I am retrieving values in onReceive of BroadcaseReceiver: 
[omitted unrelated code]

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
     Log.e("test", extras.getString("c"); <------ ERROR
     // also tried intent.getStringExtra("c");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the flag [FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) when calling [PendingIntent.getBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29). In your code:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                                 context, 0, intent, 
                                 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: I had this problem not with the getBroadcast method but with getActivity. Setting FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT solved it for me. Maybe you can also use FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037991/pendingintent-does-not-send-intent-extras)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this it will work

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);     
intent.putExtra("c", "ayush");
```

In receiver

```
intent.getStringExtra("c")
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if you are giving your onReceive(...) the correct intent as second value.

Otherwise, shouldn't the line

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

be more like

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

?