# PendingIntent does not send Intent extras

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-pendingintent

My `MainActicity`  starts `RefreshService` with a `Intent` which has a `boolean` extra called `isNextWeek`.

My `RefreshService` makes a `Notification` which starts my `MainActivity` when the user clicks on it.

this looks like this:

```
    Log.d("Refresh", "RefreshService got: isNextWeek: " + String.valueOf(isNextWeek));

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.IS_NEXT_WEEK, isNextWeek);

    Log.d("Refresh", "RefreshService put in Intent: isNextWeek: " + String.valueOf(notificationIntent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.IS_NEXT_WEEK,false)));
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("Title").setContentText("ContentText").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notification = builder.build();
    // Hide the notification after its selected
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_REFRESH, notification);
```

As you can see the `notificationIntent` should have the `boolean`extra `IS_NEXT_WEEK` with the value of `isNextWeek` which is put in the `PendingIntent`.

When I click now this `Notification` I always get `false` as value of `isNextWeek`

This is the way I get the value in the `MainActivity`:

```js
    isNextWeek = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(IS_NEXT_WEEK, false);
```

Log:

```
08-04 00:19:32.500  13367-13367/de.MayerhoferSimon.Vertretungsplan D/Refresh: MainActivity sent: isNextWeek: true
08-04 00:19:32.510  13367-13573/de.MayerhoferSimon.Vertretungsplan D/Refresh: RefreshService got: isNextWeek: true
08-04 00:19:32.510  13367-13573/de.MayerhoferSimon.Vertretungsplan D/Refresh: RefreshService put in Intent: isNextWeek: true
08-04 00:19:41.990  13367-13367/de.MayerhoferSimon.Vertretungsplan D/Refresh: MainActivity.onCreate got: isNextWeek: false
```

When I directly start the `MainActivity` with an `Intent` with the ìsNextValue` like this:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(IS_NEXT_WEEK, isNextWeek);
    finish();
    startActivity(i);
```

everything works fine and I get `true` when `isNextWeek` is `true`.

What do I make wrong that there is always a `false` value?

## UPDATE

this solves the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049676/2180161

*Quote:*

> My suspicion is that, since the only thing changing in the Intent is
>   the extras, the `PendingIntent.getActivity(...)` factory method is
>   simply re-using the old intent as an optimization.
>
> In RefreshService, try:
>
> ```
> PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
> ```
>
> See:
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

## UPDATE 2

See [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37695826/2180161) why it is better to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

Comment: PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT worked for me, thanks

Comment: you have the question and the solution :D great. I think you should add it as an answer to the ques. +10s is better than +5s ;)

Comment: Referencing to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198558/how-to-send-parameters-from-a-notification-click-to-an-activity/47156455#47156455

Comment: The FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT did not suffice in my case, since the same PendingIntent was reused by my widget. I ended up using FLAG_ONE_SHOT for the action that occurs rarely, and left the widget PendingIntent intact.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Using PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT not a good solution because of inefficient use of memory. Instead use **[PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)**.

Use also **[Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html?hl=ru#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)** (the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack).

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, FragmentPagerSupportActivity.class).
                    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);  
resultIntent.putExtra(FragmentPagerSupportActivity.PAGE_NUMBER_KEY, pageNumber);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
```

Then:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            int startPageNumber;
            if ( savedInstanceState != null)
            {
                startPageNumber = savedInstanceState.getInt(PAGE_NUMBER_KEY);
//so on
```

It should work now.

---

If you still have not expected behaviour, try to implement  `void onNewIntent(Intent intent)` event handler, that way you can access the new intent that was called for the activity (which is not the same as just calling getIntent(), this will always return the first Intent that launched your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    int startPageNumber;

    if (intent != null) {
        startPageNumber = intent.getExtras().getInt(PAGE_NUMBER_KEY);
    } else {
        startPageNumber = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This also works for PendingIntent.getBroadcast

Answer (score 22):

I think you need to update the `Intent` when you receive a new one by overriding `onNewIntent(Intent)` in your Activity. Add the following to your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent) {
    this.setIntent(newIntent);

    // Now getIntent() returns the updated Intent
    isNextWeek = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(IS_NEXT_WEEK, false);        
}
```

**Edit:**

This is needed only if your Activity has already been started when the intent is received. If your activity is started (and not just resumed) by the intent, then the problem is elsewhere and my suggestion may not fix it.

Comment: this appears also if the activity is closed and after that opened with the notification.

Answer (score 3):

Following code should work:-

```
int icon = R.drawable.icon;
String message = "hello";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("isNexWeek", true);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, pIntent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

In MainActivity onCreate:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("isNextWeek")) {
        boolean isNextWeek = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isNextWeek");
}
```

Comment: `new Notification(icon, message, when);` is deprecated

Comment: Anyway to do it without CLEAR_TOP?

Answer (score 0):

So the actual reason is that the PendingIntent will cache the previous intent if the intents only differ in their extras. In my situation no combination of `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` or `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` solves this as either the old intent will be replaced or the new one will stay the same as the initial one.
You need to ensure that Android cannot cache the Intents behind the PendingIntent. The solution for me is to make them differ in their `data` attribute.

so in the original posters code you would need to ensure that the `data` attribute is unique per each combination of extras that you are attaching.

```java
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.IS_NEXT_WEEK, isNextWeek);
    notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("myapp://nextWeek/" + (isNextWeek ? "1" : "0"))
```

Alternatively you could probably also just add a uuid to the data uri (however, if you have lots and lots of notifications, it might be nice to cache them