# Notification created by IntentService uses always a wrong Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications, intentservice

### Problem

When the user presses <kbd>Send "Button 1"</kbd>(scroll down to see the construction of the app) a new [`Notification`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) is created from the `RefreshService`. If the user presses this notification a `MainActivity` instance gets started and receives a [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) with the value `Button 1` over the [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

This value gets displayed.

When the user presses now the <kbd>Send "Button 2"</kbd> a new [`Notification`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) is created from the `RefreshService`. If the user presses this notification a `MainActivity` instance gets started and receives a [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) **ALSO** with the value `Button 1` over the [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

So as you can guess, normally there should be the value `Button 2`.

When the first Button the user pressed was <kbd>Send "Button 2"</kbd> then there would allways `Button 2` be sent.

The only sollution to get the value of the second button is to restart the phone and pressing the second button first. Even force close doesn't work.

I know that I also can change the UI in another way. But I need this approach in a app where I need to restart the 'MainActivity' with another [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) so the approach should be the same.

### Construction

- A [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) called `MainActivity`
- A [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) called `RefreshService`

***MainActivity***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final String RECEIVED = "received";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_received)).setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(RECEIVED));

        findViewById(R.id.button_1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_2).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RefreshService.class);

        if(v.getId() == R.id.button_1){
            intent.putExtra(RECEIVED, "Button 1");
            Toast.makeText(this,"Sent \"Button 1\"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.button_2){
            intent.putExtra(RECEIVED, "Button 2");
            Toast.makeText(this,"Sent \"Button 2\"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

***RefreshService***

```
public class RefreshService extends IntentService {
    public RefreshService() {
        super("RefreshService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String received = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.RECEIVED);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.RECEIVED, received);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("IntentServiceRefresh").setContentText(received).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_small).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification notification = builder.build();

        // Hide the notification after it's selected
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

***App Layout***
[image: App Layout]

Comment: Possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198558/how-to-send-parameters-from-a-notification-click-to-an-activity/1201239#1201239

Answer (score 81, accepted):

My suspicion is that, since the only thing changing in the Intent is the extras, the `PendingIntent.getActivity(...)` factory method is simply re-using the old intent as an optimization.

In RefreshService, try:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

Comment: `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` is giving me problems on Lollipop (Activity is not launched)

`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead works perfectly