# Android AlarmManager putExtra to PendingIntent and NotificationCompat.Builder

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm trying to putExtra to Activity which will be launched after clicking on notification, but instead of value that I set I'm getting default value. This is my code in AlarmReceiver:

```
    Intent notifActiv = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
    notifActiv.putExtra("ID", id);

    PendingIntent pI = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notifActiv, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(string).setTicker("You got meeting today!")
            .setContentText("Click here for more details");

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pI);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

And this is my NotificationActivity where I'm trying to get Extras:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int id = intent.getIntExtra("ID", 0);
```

Could you please tell my where I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037991/pendingintent-does-not-send-intent-extras

Comment: Thank you I haven't find this posts in google.