# PutExtra Value not being passed to mainactivity from push notification using xamarin forms and android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-notifications, main-activity

Im currently aiming to open the app to a particiualr page after the click of a push notification that successfully recieves. Il be sending an id once i get the basics working. For some reason the id is not being passed back to the mainactivity after the notification has been tapped.

BroadcastReciever class sending the push notification

```
 var uiIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
 uiIntent.PutExtra("param", "54");
 var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, 0);
```

main activity - onCreate

```
        string parameterValue = this.Intent.GetStringExtra("param");
        if (parameterValue != null)
        {
            LoadApplication(new App(parameterValue));
        }
        else
        {
            LoadApplication(new App(null));
        }
```

seems to be very simple but my parameter value is always null any thoughts thanks

UPDATE

```
 private void CreateNotification(string title, string desc)
    {
        //Create notification
        var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        Intent startupIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        startupIntent.PutExtra("param", "54");
        Android.App.TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = Android.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
        stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)));
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(startupIntent);
        const int pendingIntentId = 0;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                       stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(pendingIntentId, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

      //  var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, startupIntent, 0);


        ////Create an intent to show ui
        //var uiIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        //uiIntent.PutExtra("param", "54");
        //var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, 0);


        //Create the notification using Notification.Builder
        //Use Android Compatibility Apis

        var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.SymActionEmail)
            //we use the pending intent, passing our ui intent over which will get called
            //when the notification is tapped.
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetContentText(desc)
            .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification))

             //Auto cancel will remove the notification once the user touches it
             .SetAutoCancel(true).
            Build();


        //Show the notification
        if (notificationManager != null)
        {
            notificationManager.Notify(1, notification);
        }
    }
```

the full method with a different approach but still the value does not get passed to the mainactivity. there is always a null?

Comment: `string parameterValue = this.Intent.GetStringExtra("param");` try this function in the `onResume()` lifecycle function.

Answer (score 0):

This is what made it work for me.

initially the  RegisterInGcm(); was above parameterValue but moving it below made it work.

```
//RegisterInGcm(); Wrong

        string parameterValue = this.Intent.GetStringExtra("param");
        if (parameterValue != null)
        {
             LoadApplication(new App(parameterValue));
        }
        else
        {
            LoadApplication(new App(null));
        }

        RegisterInGcm();
```

crazy simple change, many tests to do!!

Answer (score 0):

PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent should work. Please see more at [PendingIntent does not send Intent extras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037991/pendingintent-does-not-send-intent-extras)

```
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, mailDetail, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
```